# How to draw simple diagram of jump process

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have to prepare a presentation of one paper where I need to have some simple diagrams showing how jump processes (part of financial mathematics) looks like. Here I add a picture what I need to draw.

[image: simple jump process]

I am sure, there is million ways how to draw what I need using TikZ or Forest package, but I cannot find it anywhere and I am running out of time, so I cannot now learn any of those packages from the scratch... please help.

Eventually, if also someone explained pre principle, how to draw "longer diagram" (e.g. each branch could split into two later in the same manner) I would be even more thankful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a dumb solution; a more intelligent one would automatically adjust to the labels, but requires too much time right now.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\jumpheight{0.2} % half of distance between horizonal lines [cm]
\newcommand\jumpwidth{0.1}  % horizontal distance of skewed line [cm]
\newcommand\jumplength{0.8} % total width of graphical part [cm]
\newcommand\jump[4]%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,-0.1)}]
   \draw (0,0)
         -- (\jumpwidth, \jumpheight)
         -- node[above]{\scriptsize$\scriptstyle#1$}
         (\jumplength,\jumpheight) node[right]{$#2$};
   \draw (0,0)
         -- (\jumpwidth, -\jumpheight)
         -- node[below]{\scriptsize$\scriptstyle#3$}
         (\jumplength,-\jumpheight) node[right]{$#4$};
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\begin{document}
\newcommand\dd{\mathrm{d}}
\[ = \mu\dd t + \jump{\lambda\dd t}{k-1,}{1-\lambda\dd t}{0.}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works also nested, which is basically what I needed. Thank you very much :)